# OpenTK - Transformation matrices

Tags: c#, opengl, matrix, opentk

I'm trying to create an editor for my game engine in C# WinForms using OpenTK and glControl. I'm trying to implemented the same code base in C#. I'm stuck at the transformation matrices in OpenTK.

Here is the vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 color;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = model * view * projection * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

And here is the code in C#

```
Matrix4 projectionMatrix;
Matrix4 modelMatrix;
Matrix4 viewMatrix;

modelMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;
viewMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;
projectionMatrix = Matrix4.Identity;

int modelLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(shader.getProgram(), "model");
GL.UniformMatrix4(modelLoc, false, ref modelMatrix);

viewMatrix = Matrix4.LookAt(new Vector3(0, 0, 3), new Vector3(0, 0, 3) + new Vector3(0, 0, -1.0f), new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
int viewLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(shader.getProgram(), "view");
GL.UniformMatrix4(viewLoc, false, ref viewMatrix);

projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(1.3f, glWindow.Width / (float)glWindow.Height, 1.0f, 40.0f);
int projectionLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(shader.getProgram(), "projection");
GL.UniformMatrix4(viewLoc, false, ref projectionMatrix);
```

I dont know how OpenTK deals with matrices. Nothing is displayed in the viewport. I'm i setting the matrices correctly ? My code works very well in C++ using GLM.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You're multiplying the matrices in the wrong order in your vertex shader. Matrices are multiplied in reverse order, which means you're code should be gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0f);

Comment: @enne87 Yep, that worked. Thanks !